# Disable WARNs and/or ERRORs in npm

Tags: logging, compiler-errors, npm, warnings, compiler-warnings

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) throws `errors` and `warnings` when installing.

How can you disable either one or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable those log types, you need to append a parameter to the `npm install` command.

## Disable WARNs

`WARNs` only can be disabled by adding `--loglevel=error` to the command.

```
npm install --loglevel=error
```

## Disable WARNs and ERRs

`WARNs` and also `ERRs` can be disabled by adding `--silent` to the command.

```
npm install --silent
```